# Replace ampersand(&) into %26 in the query string

Tags: php, regex, url

I am getting the query string as `q=pen&fq[category]=Pens & Refills&fq[category_id]=34`, How do I replace  `&` into `%26` only in this `Pens & Refills`, not all `&`. Please somebody help me to do this using regular expression pattern.

Comment: What do you mean "I am getting the query string"? How and why is it messed up to begin with?

Comment: Using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` I am getting the query string

Comment: I mean why is the query string messed up in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you for some reason do need to replace that character, you can do this without using a regex.

```
$string = str_replace(' & ', ' %26 ', $string);
```

Comment: Not all `&`, only if the category has the `&`

Comment: Yeah it's worked. Thanks. For simple thing I am complicating it :-(

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$regex = "~[ ]\K&~";
$replaced = preg_replace($regex,"%26",$string);
```

In the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/lL0rZ5), see the replacement at the bottom.

**Explanation**

- The `[ ]` matches a space. You don't need the brackets, but it's easier to read that way.
- The `\K` tells the engine to drop what has been matched so far from the overall match
- The `&` matches our character, and we know it was the right one because it was preceded by a space.
- We replace this with `%26`

**Option 2 for languages that don't support `\K`**

We could have used a lookbehind:

```
(?<=[ ])&
```

**Option 3 for languages that support neither `\K` nor lookbehinds**

We would have used a capture group and replaced Group 1 in a lambda:

```
[ ](&)
```

Comment: FYI added demo, explanation and options for other languages. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use positive lookbehind,

```
$regex = "~(?<=Pens ).~";
$replaced = preg_replace($regex,"%26",$string);
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tL7zS5)

Your code would be,

```
<?php
$string = 'q=pen&fq[category]=Pens & Refills&fq[category_id]=34';
$regex = "~(?<=Pens ).~";
$replaced = preg_replace($regex,"%26",$string);
echo $replaced;
?>
```

Update:

It seems like you want replace an `&` symbol which has a space before and after.

```
<?php
$string = 'q=pen&fq[category]=Pens & Refills&fq[category_id]=34';
$regex = "~ & ~";
$replaced = preg_replace($regex," %26 ",$string);
echo $replaced;
?> //=> q=pen&fq[category]=Pens %26 Refills&fq[category_id]=34
```

Comment: Thanks. Pens is not a static, It's dynamic category name. Needs to change only category has the `&`

Comment: @Rajツ it seems like you want to replace the `&` symbol which has a space before and after. I updated my code.